# Using meteor HTTP to connect to ethereum node

Tags: meteor, http-post

I am trying to copy the following curl command using [meteor HTTP](http://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html)

`curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_blockNumber","params":[],"id":83}' http://localhost:8545`

The command is from [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_blocknumber)

This is what I tried:

`HTTP.call('POST',"http://localhost:8545",{data:{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_blockNumber","params":[],"id":83}},function(res,error){console.log(res)})`

but it returns null. The curl command gives `{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":83,"result":"(the blocknumber)"}`

Comment: HTTP.call('POST',"http://localhost:8545",{data:{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_blockNumber","params":[],"id":83}},function(error,res){console.log(res)})

Comment: @iiro Thanks I'm at home atm ill try it tomorrow :)

Comment: @iiro I got this error: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:8545. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`

Comment: Did you put http:// before localhost? The SO have made a link of the url and the htt not showing up.

Comment: If I add http:// to the command you gave it becomes identical to the one in my post doesn't it?

Comment: No. Error and res are in diff order

Comment: Oh yeah I missed that. swapping the error and res does fix the problem. do you want to make this an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I answered but you can also remove this question since this is only a mistake :)

Comment: @iiro but then I wouldn't get the +2 rep for accepting the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to swap error and res params.

```
HTTP.call('POST',"http://localhost:8545",{data:{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_blockNumber","params":[],"id":83}},function(error, res){console.log(res)})
```